# C pointer assignment in external file function

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I wanted to pair a float value with an external float value representing 2 sides of a cell wall action (cellular automata). Hit a syntax wall.

I assign a pointer to a pass by reference value inside a function in a file (cell.c) outside the main.c where it is called.  The values don't pass through to the structs even when they are static and the values are wrong on output.  What did I do wrong, I even tried adding dummy vars and packing the struct. Look at these minimal yet working files compiled in GCC. Tested on Ubuntu and Fedora.

```
#include "cell.h"


// create one state variable
cell_surface_t * CreateCellSurface( float val )
{
    cell_surface_t * out;

    out  = malloc(sizeof(cell_surface_t) );
    out->st = val;
    out->p_other =  &(out->st);
    return out;
}

/*! assign a corresponding state to external variable
 * a is the state variable to work
 * in is the corresponding data value
 * */
int AssignCellSurface ( cell_surface_t * a, const float * in )
{
    a->p_other = (float *) in;

    return 0;
}

// set the internal cell value to b
float SetCellSurfaceValue ( cell_surface_t * a,  float b)
{   
    a->st = b;
    return a->st;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*! \def cell_surface_t
 * 
 * RATIONALE: one open surface may all discrete particles to ingress / egress
 * at the same time. It allows for discriminated observable data and summation.
 * 
 * cell_surface_t defines the surface state variables between two cells as defined 
 * for the flow / density and connectedness of megacities.
 * 
 * st = state of internal data vis a vis internal cell for this surface
 * p_st = external data vis a vis external connected cells data
 * 
 *
 * FOR TWO CELLS THESE ARE CROSS CONNECTED
 * internal->p_other = &external.st;
 * 
 * */

typedef struct
{
  float  st;        // cell state going out of surface
//  unsigned short int number;
  float * p_other;  // pointer to cell state going into surface from the other side / data struct
}  __attribute__ ((packed)) cell_surface_t;

// create one state variable
cell_surface_t * CreateCellSurface( float val );
// assign a corresponding state to external variable
int AssignCellSurface ( cell_surface_t * a, const float * in );
// set the internal cell value to b
float SetCellSurfaceValue ( cell_surface_t * a,  float b);
```

---

```
/*!
 *  TEST program 
 * 
 * */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cell.h"
static  cell_surface_t b;
static  cell_surface_t * c; 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float x = 100.22;
    float y = -800000.02;
    int number = 204;
    int neigh = 27;
    float z = 44.444;

    float * p_x = &y;


    c = CreateCellSurface( z ); 
    printf( "before AssignState : p_st is %f | st = %f \n", c->p_other, c->st );
    AssignCellSurface ( c, (const float *) p_x );
    SetCellSurfaceValue ( c,  x);
    x = 21.1;
    printf( "after AssignState : p_st is %f | st = %f \n", c->p_other, c->st );

    p_x = &z;
    AssignCellSurface ( c, (const float *) p_x );       
    printf( "AssignState : p_st is %f | st = %f \n", c->p_other, c->st );
    b.st = x;
    //b.st = 26.6;
    printf( "AssignState : p_st is %f | st = %f \n", b.p_other, b.st ); 
    AssignCellSurface ( &b, (const float *) p_x );
    printf( "AssignState : p_st is %f | st = %f \n", b.p_other, b.st ); 

    return 0;
}
```

[cell.c](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpxs1x8drssdgrj/cell.c?dl=0) [cell.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x4gvkm7lljkk0n4/cell.h?dl=0) [test-cca.c](https://www.dropbox.com/s/itar1xk45liiwms/test-cca.c?dl=0)

gcc -o test-cell  test-cca.c cell.c

I tried to list output and the format thinks it's code.

Comment: Next time, please do not post code as external links. Put the code directly into the question (there is now an edit pending where someone has kindly done that for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in the code.

1. `printf( "before AssignState : p_st is %f | st = %f \n", c->p_other, c->st );`.

   That's incorrect because `printf` requires the value to be printed. Not a pointer to the value. That is `c->p_other` needs to be `*c->p_other`. Same for the other `printf` calls.
2. `printf( "AssignState : p_st is %f | st = %f \n", b.p_other, b.st );`

   That has the same error as the first point. In addition, `b.p_other` is `NULL` as it has not been set. It must be set before printing it as `*b.p_other`.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I tried to submit code in code form but the corrector kept saying it was not formatted even through it was over 4 spaces. Also I wasn't sure if the bug was a file scope issue.

Comment: After fixing printfs it does not crash.